# Why does nestjs interceptor return undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, interceptor, nestjs

I am trying to implement a logging interceptor in nestjs such that, it captures all the requests and responses and logs it.

Hence I implemented a LoggingInterceptor like this

```
import { logger } from './../utils/logger';
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, from } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap, refCount, publish, publishLast } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Injectable()
    export class LoggingInterceptorInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
      intercept(context: ExecutionContext, call$: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
        const reqHeaders = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().headers;
        const reqBody = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body;
        logger.info('Logging the incoming request:',reqHeaders);
        logger.info('Logging the incoming req body:', reqBody);
        const now = Date.now();
        logger.info('Time of request call is', now);

        const serviceBehaviorSubj = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

    // response will be available only in the call$ observable stream
    // so use tap to get a clone of the observable and print the data sent

        // this pipe call transforms the response object to start with something called data
        // so a default response like "Done", "test" looks now as a json string 
        // {data : Done}  {data: test}
        // const anotherrespObs: Observable<any> = call$.pipe(publishLast(), refCount());
        // anotherrespObs.pipe(publishLast(), refCount()).subscribe(data => {
        //   logger.info('Logging the outgoing response', data);
        // });

        return call$.pipe(map(data => {
          console.log('data here is', data);
          return ({ dottted: data });
        }));
        //oo.then(return new Pro)
        // return call$.pipe(tap(() => {
        //   logger.info(`Time of completion is ${Date.now() -now}`);
        // }), map(data => {
        //   console.log('ccccccc', data);
        //   return data;
        // }));
      }
}
```

I understand that call$ operator behaves like an Observable and that will be subscribed internally by nestjs to send the response to client, but I wanted to log the information before being sent and possibly transform the response

So I make use of the map() operator of rxjs. This functions properly if the response set is of type other than 'application/json'. If the Content-Type
is of 'plain/text', the map operation gets applied and gets transformed to the desired json object and sent to the client but not in the case if the response is already of type application/json, i.e a json object. I am unable to apply the transform object. On logging the value sent to map(), I see it gets logged as undefined for json objects. So how do I get the response (even if it a json object) and possibly log it and transform it before sending it to the client in the interceptor

Note: I am wary that the response might contain sensitive information, but I probably would use log masking to just mask the response data, but this is currently for testing purposes

Here is the sample controller for which I am able to log the response in the interceptor

```
@ApiOperation({ title: 'Get - With Params', description: 'Test Method with parms' })
@Get('/getTest/:id1/:id2')
@ApiOkResponse({ description: 'Sample string is emitted' })
@ApiResponse({ status: 404, description: 'The endpoint is unavailable' })
@ApiResponse({ status: 503, description: 'The endpoint cannot be processed' })
// @Header('sampleHeaderKey', 'sampleHeaderValue')
// NOte if you send params in the URL and do not use @param then the URL will
// result in NO such end point
public getConfigDataInResponse(@Param('id1') id1: number, @Param('id2') id2: number,  @Req() req) {
  logger.info('request headers', req.headers);
  logger.info('reqiest params', req.params);
  logger.info('reqiest query params', req.query);
  logger.info('reqiest body ', req.body);
  return 'TEST';
}
```

And here is the method for which the response cannot be logged, it comes as "undefined" in the interceptor

```
public getConfigDataInResponse(@Param('id1') id1: number, @Param('id2') id2: number,  @Req() req, @Res() res) {
  logger.info('request headers', req.headers);
  logger.info('reqiest params', req.params);
  logger.info('reqiest query params', req.query);
  logger.info('reqiest body ', req.body);
  res.set('SampeHeader', 'saomevaluie');
  res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send('some data');
}
```

Comment: Please add your controller with which your problem can be reproduced. Are you injecting `@Res()` in your controller?

Comment: @KimKern I have added the controller as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you inject `@Res()` in your controller method, a lot of the features that make nest so great like interceptors won't work.

---

In most cases, you do not need to inject `@Res()` because instead you can use dedicated decorators. In your example that would be:

```
// Sets the http response code (default for POST is 201, for anything else 200)
@HttpCode(204)
// Sets a custom header
@Header('SampleHeader', 'somevalue')
@Get('/getTest/:id1/:id2')
public getConfigDataInResponse(@Param('id1') id1: number, @Param('id2') id2: number) {
  return 'some data';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kim. I suspected that it might not work since I used @Res but unsure if that was the case. Thanks for the confirmation. You are a savior with nestjs queries.

Comment: @Kim I am in a similar situation where I need to add custom headers to Response but I also want to use an interceptor where I need to add some extra fields to the response body. Is there a way in Interceptors by which I can achieve both these ?